# Mismatched button sizes in AlertDialog

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I noticed that if I create a standard two-button `AlertDialog` using the builder and one button contains text that spans more than one line and the other button fits on one line, then the button sizes are mismatched.  Only the two-line text button grows, and it looks most unpolished:

[image: Ugly AlertDialog]

Is there an easy workaround to still use the `AlertDialog` builder and coax the button sizes to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presumed this is an Android bug/feature and [reported](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32579) it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Dialog with a self build layout file. So you can manipulate the text, backgrounds, etc of the bottom buttons as you like.

Kr